# Convergence of products of sequences

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $|a_n| \in [0, 1]$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1 - |a_n| < \infty$ ($a_n$ is complex number in my case, but I think this is not important). I want to prove that

$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \prod_{n=N}^{\infty} |a_n| = 1. $$

If we denote the limit as $L$, clearly $L \leq 1$. But I can't show the converse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1 - |a_n| < \infty$ then $a_n \ne 0$ for sufficiently large $n \ge n_0$, and
$$
 \prod_{n = n_0}^\infty |a_n|
$$
converges to a nonzero value $P$. Then
$$
\prod_{n=N}^\infty a_n = \frac{P}{\prod_{n=n_0}^{N-1} |a_n|}
$$
for $n \ge n_0$, and the right-hand side converges to $P/P = 1$.